# How can I preserve big.Int.Bytes() len?

Tags: go, bigint

Given:

```
arr := make([]byte, 8)

fmt.Println(arr) // [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

big := new(big.Int).SetBytes(arr).Bytes()

fmt.Println(big) // []
```

I tried to put number 1 in and got such results:

```
... // [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] from []byte

...// [1] from big.Int
```

I have to preserve the length of 8 but `big.Int` doesn't allow it. How to be able to preserve it still?

Comment: @mkrieger1 In cryptography we do slice concatenation, where [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] + [ 1 2 3] = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3] is different to [0] + [1 2 3] = [ 0 1 2 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Int` type internally does not preserve the bytes from which it was constructed, and [`Bytes`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Bytes) returns the minimum number of bytes that are required to represent the value.

In order to turn it into a byte slice of a fixed length, use the [`FillBytes`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.FillBytes) method. You need to ensure that the value fits in the provided byte slice, otherwise it will panic.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    xarr := []byte{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(xarr)

    x := new(big.Int).SetBytes(xarr)
    fmt.Println(x)

    y := big.NewInt(0)
    y.Add(x, big.NewInt(2560))
    fmt.Println(y)

    yarr := make([]byte, 8)
    y.FillBytes(yarr)
    fmt.Println(yarr)
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3]
66051
68611
[0 0 0 0 0 1 12 3]
```

Comment: Inside a program, when I mostly operate on byte slices concatenation, I find it too complicated to process data in a big.Int form, instead I would use []byte. Am I thinking right? For example, I could input into function big.Int, inside process that in a form of []byte slice and then output the processed big.Int. It is poorly efficient, however error free (in case you forgot, that you have to fillBytes()).